# Проксирование запроса в cqrs приложениях

Tags: c#, архитектура, cqrs, чистый-код

Пишу тестовый веб-сайт, где пробую разные аспекты CQRS (сначала это была самопальная реализация cqrs, потом попробовал MediatR).

И вот что меня интересует. Насколько принято делать запросы составными, вызывая из одного запроса другой?

У меня вот есть два близких запроса:

построить отчёт за месяц

```
public class MonthReportQuery : IRequest<MonthReportDto>
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }
}
```

построить отчёт за год

```
public class YearReportQuery : IRequest<YearReportDto>
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

На выходе я получаю один и тот же набор данных отчёта, форма одинакова и различия только в шапке отчёта. Один раз требуется знать и месяц и год:

```
public class MonthReportDto
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    ... (малозначительные подробности)

    public IEnumerable<ReportItemDto> Report { get; set; }
}
```

а другой раз - только год:

```
public class YearReportDto
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    ... (малозначительные подробности)

    public IEnumerable<ReportItemDto> Report { get; set; }
}
```

В каждом случае у меня абсолютно одинаковая логика собственно запроса, который черпает данные из базы и принимает на вход среди прочего период: DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate

Какие я вижу способы выстроить аккуратно структуру классов и поменьше дублировать код:

- Создать один запрос PeriodReportQuery и не включать в ответ входные данные.
- Оставить два запроса, но отнаследовать их от абстрактного класса ReportBaseQuery в который снести одинаковую логику (выборка из базы)
- Создать ТРИ запроса (на месяц, на год, на период), при этом запросы на месяц и год будут вызывать запрос "выборка за период".

И вот сейчас я остановился на варианте с двумя запросами и базовым классом, но всё думаю, насколько жизнеспособен вариант с тремя запросами.

Возможно, в данном случае он не особо и подходит для ситуации, но может быть подобное вообще бывает нужно в приложениях построенных на базе cqrs? Сам я подобного не читал, поэтому не имею опыта.